# Using NSUserDefaults to share data to watchkit

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, watchkit

I am trying to use `NSUserDefaults` to share my data with the **WatchKit** files. I am trying to have it so when the button function is executed the `watchLabel.setText` to data from an array. The array and function that selects the data was created in the **iOS** application. (Unfortunately many resources I come across are in **objective-C** or extremely vague.)

- I have set up app groups for both iOS and Watchkit
- In my iOS **Swift** file I am trying to share my array(arrayBook) and function(.randomData) to use with the **WatchKit** controller. PS: I have no compiler errors.

  ```
  let sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.applewatchtest")

  sharedDefaults?.arrayForKey(arrayBook.randomData())

  sharedDefaults?.synchronize()
  ```
- Watchkit Controller; Unsure the correct syntax for fetching data and setting the label to random string from the array. - This is within the UIButton func.

  ```
  let sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.applewatchtest")

  let sharedArray = sharedDefaults?.arrayForKey("Shared")

  watchLabel.setText(arrayBook.randomData())
  ```

Where am I going wrong when fetching the data to set the label to data from the array which is stored in my iOS application.

Answer (score 0):

```
sharedDefaults?.arrayForKey(arrayBook.randomData())
```

This line of code is not doing anything. You're reading the array from defaults, using a key of whatever `arrayBook.randomData()` returns, and doing nothing with it.

I assume you want something like

```
sharedDefaults?.setObject(arrayBook, forKey:"Shared")
```

Which will write that array into defaults. You then get it back out in the watch (which looks fine) and get a random value using `randomData()`.

Comment: I am having compiler issues with the third line of the watchkit when calling the array and passing the method. "Use of unresolved identifier when calling "arrayBook""

Comment: That should be `sharedArray.randomData()`. `arrayBook` is out of scope for your watch controller.